# How can you fire the Button Click event without actually clicking the button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to fire the Button Click event without clicking the actual button.  Is there a way to invoke that?  I want to call the `Cancel` event and here is what I have so far:

```
protected void Cancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGridView();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in server side code or in client side javascript?

Comment: I would wrap the contents of `Cancel` in a helper method, and then you'll have the ability to call the helper method at any given moment in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the cancel method directly from within the same object:
`Cancel(null,null)`

Answer (score 2):

Since all you have is `this.BindGridView()`, which I am assuming is just another method, you can just call that instead.

However, if you wanted to do more than just that, what I usually do is create methods for all my events in the form of `OnXxx` and call that from the event handler.

So for your example, you would create an `OnCancel` method:

```
private void OnCancel()
{
    this.BindGridView();
}
```

... and then in your event handler:

```
protected void Cancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnCancel();
}
```

Doing this allows your event to trigger naturally and still function as well as allowing you the ability to call the same thing from anywhere within your code via `this.OnCancel()`.

Answer (score 1):

Server side I've done it like this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Do something

 Cancel(sender, e);
}
```